# OpenID in Java EE 6 application - how to get Principal object for user

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, servlets, jaspic

I'm playing with OpenID authentication in my app for the first time. 
I can successfully authenticate user against choosen provider, but I don't know how to correctly login user on a Java EE server, so that it looks like user was logged in with e.g. form-based login. I could use Servlet 3.0 `login` but it takes username/password pair and I don't have passwords when using OpenID.

I'd like to be able to get a `Principal` object and use `isUserInRole` method etc. Am I missing something? I'm running this app on JBoss 7.1, but I suppose there should be a common way to do that. Or maybe I'm missing something and all that stuff with `Principal` and user roles is done differently when using OpenID?

Answer (score 1):

> I suppose there should be a common way to do that.

There indeed is. You need to create a so-called JASPIC authentication module. There already is one available for OpenID, see:

- http://www-02.imixs.com/roller/ralphsjavablog/entry/openid_serverauthmodule_jsr_196_with
- http://code.google.com/p/openid4java-jsr196

> I could use Servlet 3.0 login but it takes username/password pair and I don't have passwords when using OpenID.

That's correct. You therefor need to call the Servlet 3.0 [authenticate](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#authenticate%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29) method instead. Because `login` is strongly tied to username/password it will even throw an exception in Java EE 7 when you have defined your own auth module! (in Java EE 6 it's undefined what happens, but it typically just doesn't work).

For some more examples of how to create OpenID-like auth modules in Java EE, see my own project [OmniSecurity](http://omnisecurity.omnifaces.org) and [an actual application](http://jdevelopment.nl/open-source/java-ee-kickoff-app) making using of an earlier version of that project. *(unfortunately the code is a bit difficult to follow since it needed an extremely complex and convoluted workaround to get CDI to work with a JASPIC SAM, but hopefully it still allows you to see the general pattern)*